# Python2.7.11: TypeError: expected string or buffer

Tags: python, regex, openpyxl

I am working on a script which opens a xlsx sheet, checks if a particular value is present in column 6 and if so get the corresponding value of column 2.
Getting some issue:

```
import openpyxl
import os
import time
import re

ws = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'C:\Users\Desktop\All_data_sheet.xlsx')
text_file = open(r'C:\Users\Desktop\Output.txt', "w")

topo_sheet =ws.get_sheet_by_name('Rational Web')

#Getting max rows and max columns in each sheet
topo_max_rows = topo_sheet.get_highest_row()
topo_max_columns =  topo_sheet.get_highest_column()

for ro in range(2,topo_max_rows+1):
    match = re.search(r"acl",topo_sheet.cell(row= ro , column =6).value)
    if match:
    text_file.write(topo_sheet.cell(row= ro , column =1).value)
text_file.close()
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\script.py", line 28, in <module>
    match = re.findall(r"acl",topo_sheet.cell(row= ro , column =6).value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\re.py", line 181, in findall
    return _compile(pattern, flags).findall(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer
```

Comment: what does `topo_sheet.cell(row= ro , column =6).value` return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`topo_sheet.cell(row= ro , column =6).value` is not a string for *at least one* of the cells. The returned type of a `Cell().value` reference can be an `int`, `float` or `datetime` object too, see the [`openpyxl` documentation](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/openpyxl.cell.cell.html#openpyxl.cell.cell.Cell.value):

> Get or set the value held in the cell. `:rtype:` depends on the value (string, float, int or `datetime.datetime`)

Either convert the value to a `unicode` string always (so you can use a regular expression even if that specific cell doesn't hold text) or test for the type of value produced first.

Converting to unicode, always, is easy enough:

```
match = re.search(r"acl", unicode(topo_sheet.cell(row=ro , column=6).value))
```

or test for the type first (this is definitely required if you want to match a number or date only if part of text):

```
cell = topo_sheet.cell(row=ro , column=6)
if cell.data_type == cell.TYPE_STRING:
    match = re.search(r"acl", cell.value)
```

Comment: Also, text objects are unicode so the regex should take this into consideration and it's best to avoid any conversion (at least in Python 2).

Comment: @CharlieClark: ah, did not know `unicode` objects were returned; will update. Because the *rest* of the possible types all easily convert and won't match the `acl` regular expression, conversion is safe here.

Comment: `cell.data_type` also returns the Excel type for a cell ('s' for text).

Comment: @CharlieClark: if only that was documented.. I saw the attribute but there's no explanation as to what is returned.

Comment: @CharlieClark: ah, [source code](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/openpyxl/cell/cell.html), and there are constants defined.

Comment: `cell.data_type` is one of those weird ones. Knowing whether something is a formula, text or a number might be useful but the rest are really implementation only. Might wrap stuff up in a property complete with docstring when doing the next refactoring.

Comment: See, only *now* I realise that you are the author of that library ;-)